# Svelte generate sourcemaps

Tags: javascript, typescript, svelte, vite

I'm making a website in svelte using typescript and vite. However, when I make a mistake in one of the .Svelte files and get a runtime error in the browser, the error messages point to obfustacated code which makes it impossible to debug anything. With webpack I would tell the compiler to generate sourcemaps, but I can't seem to find a similar option in the vite configs. I have "dev:true" set in my vite configs and installed the svelte debugger browser extension.

Comment: What do you mean by obfuscated? "minified"? Because if so, you should turn that off during development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option for that under [`build.sourcemap`](https://vitejs.dev/config/build-options.html#build-sourcemap), but your real issue is probably elsewhere because you should not see "obfuscated code" during development.

Maybe you are using Vite incorrectly, make sure to execute `vite dev` during development.

Comment: build.sourcemap was what I was looking for, thanks. I'm not using vite dev because I want to use my node server for development, not the built in vite server.

Comment: Then there is still the option to minify conditionally instead of dealing with production output during development. Set `build.minify` to false for the development build.

Comment: Also, you should have mentioned that in the question.